# auto-saved files in my current working directory despite I have set it to C:\temp\emacsbackup

Tags: auto-save

I have the following line in my .emacs to keep auto-saved files in a specific directory:

```
(setq backup-directory-alist (quote ((".*" . "C:/temp/emacsbackup"))))
```

And it works, I see the file, say "c:/myworkingdirectory/the_current_working_file", in that C:/temp/emacsbackup as "!drive_c!myworkingdirectory!the_current_working_file".

However, whenever I change the content in the_current_working_file, before I save it, I also see this two files in the working directory c:/myworkingdirectory/:

```
#the_current_working_file#
.#the_current_working_file
```

When I save the file the_current_working_file, these two backup disappear.

How do I prevent emacs from creating these two backups in the current working directory?

Comment: Say `C-h i g (emacs) Auto Save` and read the whole section. In particular, when disaster strikes, you might be thankful to have those files. BTW, auto-save and backup are different things.

Comment: What @NickD said. As a start, you seem to be confusing backup files with auto-save files.

Comment: I didn't mean to disable auto-save, I just want the auto-save files to be in a different directory other than the directory I am working on. Is that possible? I cannot find anything for it with M-x apropos auto-save.